# How do I link preferences.xml to my settingsTabFragment in my tablayout?

Tags: java, android

I need to add settings to my final tab and have the data be editable, however I am having trouble doing so and do not know which methods to use.

The tutorial I was following: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment

SettingsTabFragment.java

```
package com.example.sachin.pedometer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.takisoft.fix.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link SettingsTabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link SettingsTabFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SettingsTabFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private ListPreference mListPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferencesFix(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        // Indicate here the XML resource you created above that holds the preferences
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }

    /*@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mListPreference = (ListPreference)  getPreferenceManager().findPreference("preference_key");
    mListPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                // your code here
                return view;
            }
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_tab, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your problem is specifically! Are you failing to implement ListPreference? Does the app crash when you try to run? If so, provide logcat.

In the mean time, try this....

In your

> preference.xml

add this

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="@string/root_title">

<ListPreference
        android:key="list_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_list_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_list_preference"
        android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_list_preference" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

And in your

> SettingsTabFragment.java

Add this..

```
public static class SettingsTabFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat 
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private ListPreference mListPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String 
    rootKey) {
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }

   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences 
   sharedPreferences, String key) {

    setPreferenceSummery();

    }
private void setPreferenceSummery(Preference preference,Object value){

String stringValue = value.toString();

if (preference instanceof ListPreference){
// For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
// the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
mListPreference = (ListPreference) preference;

int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
//same code in one line
//int prefIndex = ((ListPreference) preference).findIndexOfValue(value);

//prefIndex must be is equal or garter than zero because
//array count as 0 to ....
if (prefIndex >= 0){
mListPreference.setSummary(mListPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
 }
} else {
// For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string 
//representation.
preference.setSummary(stringValue);
   }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to fix it. Found the right method in the docs. My apologies for not phrasing my problem better new to this side of stack overflow.

Comment: Although trying to implement the reworked code you provided but on the line

    int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

It says cannot resolve symbol "listPreference

Comment: Use   mListPreference instead